# Why System.Numerics.BigInteger cannot be used in a portable library targeting .Net 4

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

[`System.Numerics.BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.100%29) is available in .Net 4 and Silverlight 4. However, Visual Studio 2012 does not allow in portable library. Why does it want .Net 4.5?

It refuses to compile if i force it by editing project file and if I add it
using 'Add References' it updates target to .Net 4.5

Comment: Do you get an errors, or warnings, when trying use BigInteger in VS 2012? Is BigInteger even available in the IDE? According to the MSDN documentation, BigInteger is supported in the Portable Class Library, but nothing specific about version numbers is given, other then saying .NET 4.0, 4.5 and PCL are supported.

Comment: It refuses to compile if i force it by editing project file and updates target to .Net 4.5 if I add it.

Comment: You will have to give up on Windows Phone support if you need BigInteger.

Comment: I am targeting .Net 4 and Silverlight 5